# gtag.js user timing doesn't appear in report

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, gtag.js

I created a web page, tracked with Google's gtag.js, and I added a timing event using the syntax as per docs:

```
gtag('event', 'timing complete', {
  'name' : 'staring_blankly_into_space',
  'value' : 3549
});
```

The event is fired and sent properly.

When I look at my Analytics' reports:

1. there is no trace of my time-tracking events in the *User Timings* section,
2. I can find them in the *Events* section with:

Event category -> general,
Event Action -> timing complete,
Event Label -> not set

No trace of the `'name'` field to be found.

Any insight on this? (I could try and use the `'event_label'` field to set my timing description, but it's not how it's supposed to work.)

Comment: I think that in a ga event you can only send an 'action' (the second parameter), a 'category' (the 'event_category' property in the object you send as a third parameter), and a 'label' (the 'event_label' property in the object you send as a third parameter). If you want to send anything else you need to look at Custom Dimensions or Custom Metrics. Here you can read something more: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be (with *underscore*, see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-timings)):

```
gtag('event', 'timing_complete', {
  'name' : 'staring_blankly_into_space',
  'value' : 3549
});
```